# What's the best way to create a HQL query that uses a variable?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I recently started at a new company, and I notice that we're creating HQL queries in this manner (using string concatenation):

```
final Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT name FROM Foo foo WHERE email_acct_id = \'"
    + emailAccountId + "\'");
```

I suggested that we change a query like this to:

```
final Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT name FROM Foo foo WHERE email_acct_id = :email")
    .setParameter("email", emailAccountId);
```

I don't want to rock the boat too much since I'm new here, so I need facts to back up my suggestion.  What is difference between these two queries?  I'm betting it has to do with performance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason you should always the second option is security.

When you use the first option your application is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

The latter option is safer because when you use it the driver will escape the arguments appropriately before the query is executed. Check out [this](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-hibernate) article.